# Loop won't stop at given value

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a sliding panel that will hide itself with a simple js animation.
Here the developing link: http://carportal.webpronto.it
just click on "hide panel" to see the search tab go left.

The issue is the following:
I tried to give a value for the panel to stop when it reaches the position left: -25%
But the panel continue his fool run versus the infinite.
here the script i used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrollSpeed = 50;
    var step = 1;
    var current = 0;
    var endposition = 25;   
    function closeBAR(){
        current -= step;  
        if (current == endposition){


            stop;

        }



        $('#colleft').css("left",current+"%"); 



    var init = setInterval("closeBAR()", scrollSpeed);

}
</script>
```

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: `stop` isn't a JavaScript keyword.  There *is* a [`window.stop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.stop), which is what that identifier resolves to--and why there's no error thrown--but it's a function, and you don't call it.

Comment: Just a note, never pass strings to `setInterval`, it uses `eval`!  Pass functions.  `var init = setInterval(closeBAR, scrollSpeed);`

Comment: 1) You are creating multiple Intervals. Not good. 2) You are using jQuery, so why not just use `animate`?

Comment: i am not a js monster, please give me some specific hints with some examples, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line

```
stop;
```

with

```
clearInterval(init);
```

Also the endposition should be negative:

```
var endposition = -25;
```

Consider using jQuery UI effects like [Slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) instead, it will make your code more readable.

Comment: the closing bracket } should be before init.. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kR3P/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you're decrementing current, so, since it starts at 0, it ends up going into negative figures.  -25 is not the same as 25, so your 'stop' test fails

Answer (score 0):

Having a "dry" look at your code there seams to be at least the following problem: Your global var `current` will never reach the value of `endposition` since it's initialized with a value of -1 at the beginning: `current -= step == -1` (0 - 1).